# How to trim special symbols in xslt? (not spaces only)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

If I have a string = `"Hello, my friend!,,,,"` and I want to delete all that commas from right

so result will be `"Hello, my friend!"`

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
replace('Hello, my friend!,,,,',',+$','')
```